# Сериализация коллекций в jackson, запись информации о типах

Tags: java, json, serialize, коллекции, jackson

Не могу правильно сериализировать коллекцию List в jackson, проблема в том, что при сериализации объекта, содержащего коллекцию все происходит ровно, записывается информация о типах (прописанная в аннотациях). Но когда сериализируешь саму коллекцию, независимо от аннотаций не записывается никакой информации о типах, и соответственно все объекты десериализируются в LinkedHashSet. 
Вопрос состоит в том, как сериализировать лист, содержащий объекты разного типа, и восстановить этот лист правильно. Опять таки, если зафутболить эту коллекцию в другой класс все происходит правильно. Код отображает 2 метода с двумя подходами сериализации.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;

public class JSonTypeConversion {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        listSerialization();
        objectWithListSerialization();

    }
    /*
     * Сериализация коллекции
     */
    public static void listSerialization() throws Exception{
        List<BasicClass> list = new ArrayList<BasicClass>();
        list.add(new BasicClass("Basic"));
        list.add(new ExtendedClass("Extended","LatName"));
        list.add(new SuperExtendedClass("Super","LastName",456));

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String serializedString = mapper.writeValueAsString(list);
        //Нет записи о типах, дальнейшая десериализация не имеет смысла
        System.out.println(serializedString);

    }
    /*
     * Сериализация объекта, содержащего коллекцию
     */
    public static void objectWithListSerialization() throws Exception{
        ClassHolder set = new ClassHolder();

        set.add(new BasicClass("Basic"));
        set.add(new ExtendedClass("Extended","LatName"));
        set.add(new SuperExtendedClass("Super","LastName",456));

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String serializedString = mapper.writeValueAsString(set);

        System.out.println(serializedString);

        ClassHolder resulnList = mapper.readValue(serializedString, ClassHolder.class);

        System.out.println(resulnList);
        //Полное восстановление объекта, все ок
        System.out.println(resulnList.get(2).getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

}
/*
 * Иерархия классов для экспериментов
 */
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,  property="className")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=BasicClass.class, name="BasicClass"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=ExtendedClass.class, name="ExtendedClass"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=SuperExtendedClass.class, name="SuperExtendedClass")
})      
class BasicClass{

    public String name;

    public BasicClass(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public BasicClass(){

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "basicClass [name=" + name + "]";
    }

}
class ExtendedClass extends BasicClass{
    public String lastName;

    public ExtendedClass(){

    }

    public ExtendedClass(String name,String lastName) {
        super(name);
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "extendedClass [lastName=" + lastName + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }

}
class SuperExtendedClass extends ExtendedClass{

    public int id;

    public SuperExtendedClass(){

    }

    public SuperExtendedClass(String name,String lastName, int id) {
        super(lastName, name);
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "superExtendedClass [id=" + id + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }   
}
/*
 * Класс, содержащий коллекцию внутри
 */
class ClassHolder{
    @JsonDeserialize(as=ArrayList.class,contentAs=BasicClass.class)
    private List<BasicClass> objList = new ArrayList();

    public List<BasicClass> getObjList() {
        return objList;
    }

    public BasicClass get(int i) {
        return objList.get(i);
    }

    public void setObjList(List<BasicClass> objList) {
        this.objList = objList;
    }
    public void add(BasicClass obj){
        objList.add(obj);
    }
}
```